# Why does this only generate one random string? [Java]

Tags: java, string

```
public class TavernNameGen {

private static final String TXT_PLACE_NAME  = buildingText();
private static final String TXT_VERBING     = verbText();
private static final String TXT_NOUN        = nounText();

private static final String NAME =
        "Welcome to the  "+
                "\n \n "+
                TXT_PLACE_NAME+
                " of the "+
                TXT_VERBING +
                TXT_NOUN +
                "."
;


public static void read(  ) {

    GameScene.show(new WndMessage(NAME));

}


public static String buildingText()
{
    String buildingType;
    switch (Random.Int(1,4))
    {
        case 1: buildingType = "Inn";
            break;
        case 2: buildingType = "Inn";
            break;
        case 3: buildingType = "Tavern";
            break;
        case 4: buildingType = "Pub";
            break;
        default: buildingType = "Inn";
            break;
    }
    return buildingType;
}

public static String verbText()
{
    String verbName;
    switch (Random.Int(1,20))
    {
        case 1: verbName = " Dancing";
            break;
        case 2: verbName = " Prancing";
            break;
        case 3: verbName = " Eating";
            break;
        case 4: verbName = " Jigging";
            break;
        case 5: verbName = " Digging";
            break;
        case 6: verbName = " Flogging";
            break;
        case 7: verbName = " Floating";
            break;
        case 8: verbName = " Flying";
            break;
        case 9: verbName = " Laughing";
            break;
        case 10: verbName = " Smiling";
            break;
        case 11: verbName = " Drowning";
            break;
        case 12: verbName = " Golden";
            break;
        case 13: verbName = " Silver";
            break;
        case 14: verbName = " Copper";
            break;
        case 15: verbName = " Farming";
            break;
        case 16: verbName = " Running";
            break;
        case 17: verbName = " Sewing";
            break;
        case 18: verbName = " Black";
            break;
        case 19: verbName = " White";
            break;
        case 20: verbName = " Fighting";
            break;
        default: verbName = " Gesticulating";
            break;
    }
    return verbName;
}

public static String nounText()
{
    String nounName;
    switch (Random.Int(1,20))
    {
        case 1: nounName = " Pony";
            break;
        case 2: nounName = " Horse";
            break;
        case 3: nounName = " Griffin";
            break;
        case 4: nounName = " Dragon";
            break;
        case 5: nounName = " Wench";
            break;
        case 6: nounName = " Bastard";
            break;
        case 7: nounName = " Ogre";
            break;
        case 8: nounName = " Troll";
            break;
        case 9: nounName = " Ox";
            break;
        case 10: nounName = " Cow";
            break;
        case 11: nounName = " Cock";
            break;
        case 12: nounName = " Hen";
            break;
        case 13: nounName = " Ram";
            break;
        case 14: nounName = " Ewe";
            break;
        case 15: nounName = " Dog";
            break;
        case 16: nounName = " Merchant";
            break;
        case 17: nounName = " Fisherman";
            break;
        case 18: nounName = " Arborist";
            break;
        case 19: nounName = " Archer";
            break;
        case 20: nounName = " Gallbladder";
            break;
        default: nounName = " Pancreas";
            break;
    }
    return nounName;
}
```

}

When I run this, it generates a string for a tavern name. My problem is that when I run it in my program, it will only generate a new string when I compile the program again. If I exit the program and run it again, it will generate the same string.
What am I missing here?
The class is executed from only one outside class by the command TavernNameGen.read();

Comment: Where is Random defined?

Comment: It's defined in a utilities folder. It's not exactly java's random. Good point, though, I hadn't thought that this could be the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the variables `static`. This means that they retain their values between calls to the procedure, and that the initialization (by calling the verbText(), etc. gets done only ONCE, the first time the method is called. Remove `static` and it should work as you expect.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I always had a hard time understanding what static does. Learning, as always, is fun. A sincere thank you for helping me in this.